# Cosuming web-service with JAX-WS

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I need to be able to read the host name and port from the web.xml file before every call to the ws.  So how can I do this in JAX-WS or isn't it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You would access the parameters as you would for any other purpose:

[`ServletContext.getInitParameter(String key)`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getInitParameter(java.lang.String))